# javascript to control css

Tags: javascript, css

I have a progress bar that have a width.
I want this width to change with javascript depending on the percentage that i have.
This is the code i am using and it's working well

```
while (progress.hasChildNodes()){
                progress.removeChild(progress.firstChild);
            }
            progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Math.round(percent * 100) +' %'));
            document.getElementById("inner-progressbar").style.width= "90%";
        }
```

all i want to do is to put the value of

```
Math.round(percent * 100) +' %'
```

in the width in place of 90%

```
width= "90%"
```

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 3):

What's the problem?

```
document.getElementById("inner-progressbar").style.width = 
    Math.round(percent * 100) + '%';
```

Comment: not working i think it need "" or anything like concatunation

Comment: You could take out the space in front of the `%`, you don't need it. What is `percent`'s value? Are you making sure it is `.9` not `90`?

Comment: width should get he value is this form width = " " ;

Comment: @Jordan yea right that was the problem the space working fine now thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("inner-progressbar").style.width = 
    Math.round(percent * 100) +' %';

it is right but the space before % is the problem so the right code is like that

```
document.getElementById("inner-progressbar").style.width = 
    Math.round(percent * 100) +'%';
```